# How to find min and max values in a range and populate it to a new column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, numpy

Assuming I have a dataframe like this:

```
# importing pandas and numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a sample dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : [ 1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 3, 5, 15, -1, -12, 11, -2, -3, 12, 22],
    'B' : [ -1, -2, -3, 12, -12, -3, 5, 23, -1, 11, -3, -1, 4, 12, 23]
})
```

Such that the data looks like:

```
     A   B
0    1  -1
1    2  -2
2    3  -3
3   -1  12
4   -2 -12
5    3  -3
6    5   5
7   15  23
8   -1  -1
9  -12  11
10  11  -3
11  -2  -1
12  -3   4
13  12  12
14  22  23
```

What if I want to create a column that find the Min values of the next 7 rows, such that it looks like this:

```
     A   B Min A
0    1  -1    -2
1    2  -2    -2
2    3  -3    -2
3   -1  12   -12
4   -2 -12   -12
5    3  -3   -12
6    5   5   -12
7   15  23   -12
8   -1  -1   -12
9  -12  11   N/A
10  11  -3   N/A
11  -2  -1   N/A
12  -3   4   N/A
13  12  12   N/A
14  22  23   N/A
```

In this example we find the min value in column A, row 0 to 6, row 1 to 7, and so on, and populate it in the 'Min A' column and so on.

Is there a way to do this for Min and Max values for both A and B such that there are now 4 additional columns i.e. Min A, Max A, Min B, Max B?

Appreciate all of you for the help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do rolling on reversed data:

```
for col in ['A','B']:
    data[f'Min {col}'] = data[col].iloc[::-1].rolling(7).min()
    data[f'Max {col}'] = data[col].iloc[::-1].rolling(7).max()
```

Outpu:

```
     A   B  Min A  Max A  Min B  Max B
0    1  -1   -2.0    5.0  -12.0   12.0
1    2  -2   -2.0   15.0  -12.0   23.0
2    3  -3   -2.0   15.0  -12.0   23.0
3   -1  12  -12.0   15.0  -12.0   23.0
4   -2 -12  -12.0   15.0  -12.0   23.0
5    3  -3  -12.0   15.0   -3.0   23.0
6    5   5  -12.0   15.0   -3.0   23.0
7   15  23  -12.0   15.0   -3.0   23.0
8   -1  -1  -12.0   22.0   -3.0   23.0
9  -12  11    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
10  11  -3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
11  -2  -1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
12  -3   4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
13  12  12    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
14  22  23    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

You can also roll on the dataframe like:

```
data[['A','B']].iloc[::-1].rolling(7).agg(['min','max'])
```

which gives a double-leveled-column dataframe (notice the reversed index):

```
       A           B      
     min   max   min   max
14   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
13   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
12   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
9    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
8  -12.0  22.0  -3.0  23.0
7  -12.0  15.0  -3.0  23.0
6  -12.0  15.0  -3.0  23.0
5  -12.0  15.0  -3.0  23.0
4  -12.0  15.0 -12.0  23.0
3  -12.0  15.0 -12.0  23.0
2   -2.0  15.0 -12.0  23.0
1   -2.0  15.0 -12.0  23.0
0   -2.0   5.0 -12.0  12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shift it by `n-1`

```
n = 7
data.rolling(n, closed="right").min().shift(-(n-1))
# OR
pd.concat([data, data.rolling(n, closed="right").agg(["min", "max"]).shift(-(n-1))], axis=1)
```